# Unknown name of the following: class Foo::Bar

Tags: c++

I was reading a program in c++ and came across the following

```
class Foo::Bar
{
   ...
}
```

I have been researching different methods of class implementation but have not come across the :: when creating a class.  Do you know the name of it so I can look it up?

Foo is a full size class, not a namespace.  I do not know what Bar is.

Thank you

Comment: The class Bar is nested inside of Foo. This is similar to a method definition such as `void Foo::DoSomething(...) { }`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is a nested class definition. It means that the class `Bar` was declared inside class `Foo`. Kind of like this:

```
class Foo
{
...
class Bar;
...
};
```